# MongoDB insert Error: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed

Tags: python, mongodb

Using Python 3 and MongoDB 2.6 and trying to insert some data into my collection, here is the sample code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pymongo import MongoClient

urlList = ['http://....'] #bunch of URLs
jsArray = []
cssArray = []

client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 28017)
db = client.tagFinderProject  # Getting the DB
collection = db.tegFinder     # Getting the Collection

for url in urlList:
    parsed_uri = urlparse(url)
    domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    for lines in soup.find_all('script'):
        if lines.get('src') is not None and '.js' in lines.get('src') and 'http' in lines.get('src'):
            jsArray.append(lines.get('src'))
        elif str(lines.get('src')).startswith('//'):
            jsArray.append('http:' + lines.get('src'))
        elif lines.get('src') is not None and '.js' in lines.get('src') and 'http' not in lines.get('src'):
            jsArray.append(domain + lines.get('src'))

for lines in soup.find_all('link'):
    if lines.get('href') is not None and (lines.get('href')).endswith('.css') and 'http' in lines.get('href'):
        cssArray.append(lines.get('href'))
    elif lines.get('href') is not None and (lines.get('href')).endswith('.css') and 'http' not in lines.get('href'):
        cssArray.append(domain + lines.get('href'))

uniqueJS = list(set(jsArray))
uniqueCSS = list(set(cssArray))

for js in uniqueJS:
    collection.insert('JS: ', js)
for css in uniqueCSS:
    collection.insert('CSS: ', css)
```

Ofcourse before I run this I start my MongoDB server and here what it says:

```
2015-05-13T11:25:03.942-0500 [initandlisten] options: { net: { http: { RESTInterfaceEnabled: true, enabled: true } }, storage: { dbPath: "D:\Projects\mongoDB" } }
2015-05-13T11:25:03.944-0500 [initandlisten] journal dir=D:\Projects\mongoDB\journal
2015-05-13T11:25:03.944-0500 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-05-13T11:25:04.045-0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-05-13T11:25:04.045-0500 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
```

I run the above Python code and I get :

```
  File ".../TagFinder/tagFinder.py", line 91, in <module>
    collection.insert('JS: ', js)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1924, in insert
    with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 663, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 121, in select_server
    address))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 97, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed
```

Can't find why I'm getting this. I can insert data via using the cmd promt and I can display it at `127.0.0.1/tagFinderProject/tagFinder/`

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

**EDIT 1:**

If I change the `client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 28017)` to `client = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/')`

I get:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Referring to: `collection.insert('JS: ', js)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem;

Feeling dumb thanks to my typo. 
1) Collection name: `tegFinder` but I'm trying to get `127.0.0.1/tagFinderProject/tagFinder/`

2) MongoDB can't insert `Strings` but only `dict` meaning it needs a *key:value* pair. So I've changed it to:

```
dictJS = {'JS: ': js}
collection.insert(dictJS)
```

3) Not a part of the solution but I've leave the connection empty:

```
client = MongoClient()        # Instead 'cliecnt = MongoClient(mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017, 28017')
db = client.tagFinderProject  # Getting the DB
collection = db.tegFinder
```